# Google Photos Search vs Drive Search results difference

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-photos, google-drive-search

I've just encountered a weird behavior on the Google photos search.
I have a Google account which I'm using only for storing photos.

All the photos are uploaded via the Google photos app (so there are no photos in any folder on drive, only under the "Google Photos" tab).

**When I search for a photo via the drive interface I get way more results** than searching via the Google photos app on my mobile or the [photos website](https://photos.google.com/).

I discovered that the original filename affects the search results on drive, so I removed all the photos and uploaded them again with filenames that consist of only numbers, and also checked there are no tags in the meta-data.

But drive still shows more results than the photos app/website.

Any ideas why?